# GitLab CI: How can I set environment variables in main branch based on merge requests labels?

Tags: gitlab-ci

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` automatically deploys if all tests have passed in the main branch.
But sometimes I want to temporarily stop this automatic deployment by, for example, labels added to merge requests.
I think I can do this if CI jobs in the main branch can know which labels were added to the merge requests merged to the main branch, like this:

```
deploy:
  ...
  rules:
    if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_LABELS contains "disable-auto-deploy"
    when: never
```

But I'm not sure how to get the labels in the main branch CI jobs. I found I can get it through [CI_MERGE_REQUEST_LABELS](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)  in merge request pipelines, but how can I do this in the main branch?